# Master-detail data binding

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, windows-8.1

I have two models in my application:

```
class Line
{
    string line_id  { get; set; }
    string color { get; set; }
}

class Point 
{
    string point_id { get; set; }
    string line_id { get; set; }
    int weight { get; set; }
}
```

And I have two ObservableCollection:

```
lines - ObservableCollection<Line>
points - ObservableCollection<Point>
```

I want to display two ListBox'es : first (outer) to display lines, and second (inner) to display the points which belongs **to this line**.

```
<ListView x:Name="lvPoint" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding color, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SOMETHING, Mode=TwoWay}">
              <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                  <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding weight, Mode=OneWay}" />                                                
                  </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
              </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
           </ListBox>
       </StackPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 </ListView>
```

I set DataContext for outer ListBox in the code:

```
lvPoint.DataContext = lines;
```

How can I set DataContext for inner ListBox to display Points for each Line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Line` model is not good for this scenario. It should have a property such as called `Points` which contains the interested points belonging to the Line. Then the Binding is just simple:

```
class Line {
  public string line_id  { get; set; }
  public string color { get; set; }
  ObservableCollection<Point> _points;
  public ObservableCollection<Point> Points {
    get {
        if (_points == null) _points = new ObservableCollection<Point>();
        return _points;
    }
  }
}
```

Then in XAML code you can just set the `Path` to `Points` like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Points, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
          <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding weight, Mode=OneWay}" />                  
          </StackPanel>
       </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The model above is just an example showing the main idea. The full implementation should of course be different and more advanced depending on the current project.

**Update**: Without using the model above, you can try using `Converter` for the `Binding`. The `Binding` is set directly to the current item (Line). The `Converter` will convert `Line` to `points` (maybe based on `line_id` and your query method):

```
public class LineToPointsConverter : IValueConverter {
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                         System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture){
      var line = value as Line;
      //convert to points by querying the points based on line.line_id here
      return ...
   }
   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
                             object parameter, 
                             System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture){
      return Binding.DoNothing;
   }                             
}
```

Define a static property of `LineToPointsConverter` or create an instance of that converter in `Resources`:

```
<Window.Resources>
   <local:LineToPointsConverter x:Key="lineToPointsConverter"/>  
</Window.Resources>
```

Then in XAML code set that converter:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=.,
                             Converter={StaticResource lineToPointsConverter}}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
          <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding weight, Mode=OneWay}" />                  
          </StackPanel>
       </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: I use ORM which can not serialize such collection property, but thanks anyway.

Comment: @demas I'm afraid that this is the only approach, the most intuitive and conforms to the XAML's model. Anyway the `Binding` inside the inner ListBox has the context of the current item (Line). Changing the context should also change the bound points collection. The `points` collection in your code is unclear here (where it locates?) or it is a member of the `DataContext`? If so it's a mixed points of all the Lines?

Comment: It is a separate collections (each collection corresponds to one table in DB). I use line_id property in Line and Point to link points to the Line.

Comment: @demas I'm not familiar with ORM. Looks like you can use a Binding Converter or a custom MarkupExtension to get points from line. See my update for one of those approaches (using Converter). I'm not sure if that works but it's worth trying.